# PHP - Get data from POST and POST to another url to imrpove performance

Tags: php, api

I have a URL, example.com/api-handler/handler1.php.

One of our SMS service provider push data to the above URL.

The URL above contains a lot of condition, and takes 20-30 seconds to process the data.

Due to huge processing time, the SMS service provider is encountering some performane issue at their end.

What i have did so far, is created another URL with same code i.e. example.com/api-handler/handler2.php.

And then modified the code of handler1.php. Now the handler1.php just takes the data and post it to handler2.php using CURL.

I did it because i thought it will respond the SMS server within 2-3 seconds, but the processing time is still the same.

I can use sessions to get rid of this, but cannot use sessions as the data we are receiving are so frequent.

Is there any other way to respond faster to the service provider on handler1.php and then process the data on handler2.php later?

Comment: what are you looking for is a queue worker. you recieve a message in your second handler - push it to queue and after a worker will fetch messages from the queue and do it job postponed. read about rabbitMQ or redisMQ stuff.

Comment: @myxaxa Thanks for your valuable suggestion. However the solution shared by gbalduzzi worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that curl requests in PHP are blocking. This means that your first file `handler1.php` will wait until `handler2.php` processed everything.

The best solutions would be to use a proper queue service: from `handler.php` you add your data to the queue and then it will be processed by the second file.

A more trivial and less robust solution would be to set a low `CONNECTION_TIMEOUT` value on the cURL request, so that your first script stop waiting for the cURL request to finish:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 200);
```

Comment: Thank you so much @gbalduzzi. Setting the timeout method works.

Comment: Happy to help :)